# Add tracking link to mail

Tags: email-templates, magento-1.7, shipment-tracking

**How do I add a tracking link to mail template?**

Here is what I tried:

In `System > Transactional Emails` I opened the template for `Shipment Email Template for Guest  (GLOBAL)`. I thought tracking numbers are included here:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/shipment/track.phtml'
  shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
```

So I copied `email/order/shipment/track.phtml` into my template and added a tracking link but it does not show up in the email:

```
<td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:3px 9px"><a href="http://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/set_identcodes.do?lang=de&idc=<?php echo $_item->getNumber() ?>"><?php echo $_item->getNumber() ?></a></td>
```

Comment: You're on the right track with the template file, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30192557/2274303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this is PHP code:

```
<td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:3px 9px">
<a href="http://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/set_identcodes.do?lang=de&idc=
<?php echo $_item->getNumber() ?>">
<?php echo $_item->getNumber() ?></a>
</td>
```

You can't execute PHP from inside of an email template - instead, look to a tutorial to implement:

http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/how-do-i-add-tracking-link-to-shipment-transactional-email-63-nbsp--82195.html

Or an extension:

http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/mobile-order-tracking.html

This plugin has the following feature which sounds handy to insert into your transactional shipment email: "Ability to insert order tracking link via widget and CMS"

Comment: The PHP code is not in the template but in a block the template includes. Anyway that does work, I have the tracking number in the email. What I am missing is my HTML link around it. I am guessing the block generation in emails ignores my template but I don't want to change /app/design/frontend/base/default/